# Should I interfere the normal Python garbage collection process

Tags: python

I have a large hierarchical data set in Python. After I am done with it, I need to get rid of it -- so I just do a `del` on the root node of the hierarchy.

Would it be OK to manually do a `gc.collect()` -- is it a good practice to remove large data quickly or should I not do it and let Python do it's business?

What are (if any) the correct patterns to use `gc` manually?

Comment: I'd tell to you that the usual advice is to leave the GC/reference counting do its work, but, coming from C++, often I find myself intuitively `del`ing stuff/not trusting the GC more than I would think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CPython garbage collector is still largely based on reference counting, so if your data structure is truly hierarchical (does not contain circular references), a `del` on the last reference to it should clear it from memory and there's no need to use the `gc` module.

That being said, I'd recommend not even using `del`. It's far more elegant to set up your functions in such a way that the last reference to a data structure simply disappears when the last function to use it returns:

```
def load():
    return some_huge_data_structure

def process(ds):
    do_whatever_to(ds)

process(load())  # after this, the huge DS will be gone
```

Comment: I don't have circular refs. But are you saying that if I had them, running `gc` would be necessary?

Comment: I am actually writing a server, and the data has to persist across requests -- so I can't not use `del` and just let the data go away as you described.

Comment: python gc is *only* used for circular refs.  reference counting does the rest.

Comment: @good_computer: if you had circular references, then you should still trust the Python GC to clean stuff up on its own, unless you hit a situation where it clearly doesn't do its job.

Comment: And how do I know it's NOT doing the job?

Comment: @good_computer: ok, I can see a potential use for `del` in your situation. However, reassigning variables has the same effect of clearing references to the variables' old values.

Comment: @good_computer: you have an indication that GC is not doing its job when memory use keeps rising (assuming you're not also running a C extension that contains memory leaks).

Comment: And even when you have circular references, it's quite possible that the `gc` module is not the optimal solution, but that `weakref`s are, instead.

Answer (score 1):

When CPython garbage collects something it doesn't always actually return that memory back to the operating system.

Python uses a complicated system of memory "arenas" and "pools" (see http://www.evanjones.ca/memoryallocator/ for example). Objects live in those pools and arenas, and memory is only returned to the OS when a whole memory arena has been garbage collected.

That means that in a worst case you could have 1000 objects that occupy 250MB of memory, just because each object lives in its own arena, which might be 256k large. Now Python allocates memory in a pretty clever way, so this worst case (almost) never happens.

If you constantly allocate and de-allocate tons of very differently-sized objects, then you might into these memory fragmentation problems. In that case Python doesn't return much memory to the OS, and sadly you can't do much about it.